# One custom cell in UICollectionView swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a page in my App with a slider on top and a repeated list on the bottom. now I'm looking for a solution that can be done this entire UI with a single `UICollectionView`, is that possible to have a single cell with custom design and dataSoruce from other cells?

Here is my design:
[image]

Or should I use tow different `UICollectionView` separately? what is the best solution out there?

Also, I created UI programmatically. is not Storyboard.

Comment: You can use two sections in collection view . here , first section will have only one item, and other would have as per your array, You can create XIB files and register with collection view

Comment: @MikeAlter first one is not only one item. it's also an array of items. like bottom list.

Comment: As far as I understood design the bottom section scrolls vertically while top section scrolls horizontally. To achieve this behaviour you will need to use 2 collection views or deeply customized collection view layout that would respond separately for user actions regarding in what section the action took place (better use 2 collection views ).

Comment: I know but you are in confusion bro, whatever item you are showing in first section you have to pass 1 if you pass more than it will show in list not one, and that items should be managed in custom cell class, Getting my point ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comment you have to take

1. One collection view
2. Two Sections

In section one pass items : 1

In Section  two pass items: Array count

gallery here is sample code

```
    GalleryCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kGalleryCell forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.gestureRecognizers.count <= 0) {
        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeNext = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellDidSwipe:)];
        swipeNext.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;

        UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipePrev = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(cellDidSwipe:)];
        swipePrev.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;

        [cell setGestureRecognizers:@[swipeNext,swipePrev]];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. but I don't understand obj-c :) is possible to put Swift version of this code plz.